# How to redirect a page to another page when refresh at second attempt

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-refresh

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
   alert("");window.location="index.html";
  }
</script>
```

I tried this code, but it is not working.

Comment: what are you trying to do? keep users from leaving your site? But only the second time they try and leave?

Comment: @sss if my code solves your probem vote for answer and mark as accepted answer so that other peoples can use this code.

Answer (score 15):

In `bbb.jsp`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
    window.setTimeout(function () { 
        window.location = 'AAA.jsp';
    }, 0); 
    window.onbeforeunload = null; // necessary to prevent infinite loop, that kills your browser 
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly! @Lokesh, Could you please explain how this works? How does it work with setTimeOut function?

Answer (score 3):

Windows onload loads after all the content is loaded, little bit slow other workaround is to use document.onload(Browser compatibility issue)

```
window.onload = function () {
  window.location = "/allotment";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

below code will work for you

```
function confirmExit()
{
 alert("exiting");
 window.location.href='index.html';
 return true;
}
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
```

Answer (score 1):

In bbb.jsp file

```
<script>
    submitFormOkay = false;
    $(document.body).on("click", "a", function() {
        submitFormOkay = true;
    });
    window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        if (!submitFormOkay) {
            window.setTimeout(function () { 
                window.location = "index.html";
            }, 0); 
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I hope this will help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me.  Not the second attempt part, but changing URL after showing the popup.  If you hit cancel, the function is not ran.  If you click "Reload", the function is called and you will be redirected.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
  $(window).on('unload', function() {
    window.location.href = 'index.html';
  });

  return 'Not an empty string';
});
```