# Reload icon clicked or F5 clicked? Redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, browser, reload

I want to make a page that redirects users when they reload the page clicking the browser icon or F5, but not when they open the page. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect a page to another page when refresh at second attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622892/how-to-redirect-a-page-to-another-page-when-refresh-at-second-attempt)

Comment: Already tryed, but onbeforeunload work when I try to leave the page, and not when I reload it.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, so I will just link to another post here that should give you the solution you are looking for: [Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript)

So based on that answer, you just do something like this...

```
//check for Navigation Timing API support
if (window.performance) {
  console.info("window.performance works fine on this browser");
}

if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
 console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
 window.location = "/redirect_url"; // The url you want
} else {
 console.info( "This page is not reloaded");
}
```

Comment: @Matt What about it doesn't work? If you check the console logs what does it say?

Comment: The answer from the original comes from this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation, which seems to have been deprecated. It is replaced with this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type. What happens if you change the if statement to this 'if (performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type == "reload")'?

Comment: I’ve changed the if, but when i reload nothing happens. My console prints “This page is not reloaded”

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome .

Comment: Try just typing 'performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type' into your console. What does it respond with?